# Append <i> tag before and after every fourth set of words

Tags: c#

I have written a method like below lines of code

```
public string SplitLine(string input)
{
    var wordList = input.Split(' ');
    var sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int index = 0; index < wordList.Length; index++)
    {
        sb.Append("<i>" + wordList[0]);
        if (index % 4 == 0 && index > 0)
            sb.Append("<br/></i>" + wordList[index]);
        else
            sb.Append(wordList[index] + ' ');
    }
    return sb.ToString();
}
```

Basically I want that it should append `<i>` tag and `<br/>` after every fourth set of words for e.g

If string contains "Hello this is james, i am a web designer by profession. I love web designing"

Then output should be like

```
<i>Hello this is james,</i><br/>
<i>i am a web designer</i><br/>
<i>by profession. I love</i><br/>
<i>web designing. </i>
```

Comment: Eh, `"i am a web designer"` contains *five* words?

Comment: Why do you need to do that? Is this homework?

Comment: Use a debugger, it's a simple set of mistakes

Comment: please provide me the improved version of the code

Comment: You have code, what is the wrong result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Linq* solution (providing that `"i am a web designer"` is just an *error* and
the right 4 words chunk should be `"i am a web"`) colud be:

```
  String text = 
    "Hello this is james, i am a web designer by profession. I love web designing";

  String result = String.Join(Environment.NewLine, text
    .Split(' ')
    .Select((item, index) => new {
        Text = item,
        Index = index / 4
      })
    .GroupBy(data => data.Index, data => data.Text)
    .Select(data => "<i>" + String.Join(" ", data) + "</i><br/>"));
```

the `result` will contain

```
<i>Hello this is james,</i><br/>
<i>i am a web</i><br/>
<i>designer by profession. I</i><br/>
<i>love web designing</i><br/>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
sb.Append("<i>"  + wordList[0] + ' ');
for (int index = 1; index < wordList.Length; index++)
{        
    if (index % 4 == 0)
        sb.Append("</i><br/>\n<i>" + wordList[index] + ' ');
    else
        sb.Append(wordList[index] + ' ');
}
sb.Append("</i><br/>");
```

If there are any more small issues, fix them. Otherwise whats the point of learning

Answer (score -1):

I like linq for this type of thing:

```
var input = "Hello this is james, i am a web designer by profession. I love web designing";
var inputList = input.Split(' ');
var nrOfLastItem = inputList.Length - 1;

var result = inputList.Select((word, nr) =>
                               ((nr % 4) == 0 ? "<i>" : "") 
                                  + word 
                                  + ((nr % 4) == 3 || (nr == nrOfLastItem) 
                                     ? "</i><br />" 
                                     : " "));

var output = String.Join("", result);
```

I'm sure you can guess what the result will be.